# trouble with a .sh script on mac

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to make a script that goes to 411.com and finds info about the person you are looking for:

```
clear
echo -n "Nombre: "
read fname
echo

#Por si no responde el usr
if [[ -z $fname ]]; then
  echo
  echo "No has introducido un Nombre."
  exit
fi
echo -n "Apellido: "
read lname

#Por si no responde el usr
if [[ -z $lname ]]; then
  echo
  echo "No has introducido un Apellido."
  exit
fi
echo "Buscando a: $fname $lname"
echo "========================="
echo
sleep 1
echo "Encontrado: $fname $lname "
echo "=========================="
echo
read -p "Presionas <enter>"

google -new-tab http://www.411.com/name/$fname - $lname/ &`enter code here`
```

and it gives this error:

./find.sh: line 31: google: command not found

im using macosx sierra just in case it helps

Comment: Are you sure google is a command you can run in the shell? That's quite unusual. There are ways to connect programmatically to websites, not sure this is one. You may have meant google-chrome, see :http://askubuntu.com/questions/234663/what-command-should-i-type-to-run-chrome-from-the-terminal#234665, but that's still not for terminals, but gui based (unless you want to open an actual window).

Answer (score 0):

That error means that there is no such thing as a `google` command in the shell. Why would there be, when you could just do `open http://411.com/...`?

Comment: The last sentence isn't really relevant.

Comment: It's an alternative solution

Comment: Only if you don't necessarily care which application opens the URL.